# Create dot pathed type definition based on recursive object

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I have a have a nested object of functions of type:

```
type CallbackFn = (args: any) => any
type CallbackObj = {
  [key: string]: CallbackFn | CallbackObj
}
const callbacks = {
  foo: function(args: { x: num }): string {
    return "test";
  },
  bar: {
    bar1: function(): boolean {
      return true;
    },
    bar2: function(): number {
      return 10;
    }
  },
  baz: {
    baz1: {
      baz2: function(args: { key: string }): string {
        return "test";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In another part of the system I have an interface definition that looks like this:

```
interface FieldDef {
  name: string
  type: string
  callback: CallbackDef
}

interface CallbackDef {
  fn: string
  settings: any
}
```

The ultimate goal is that when a user declares what callback to use for a specific `FieldDef` it auto-completes the possible callback fns, and then auto-completes the settings that callback might take. So in the above cases the possible `fn` entries are `"foo" | "bar.bar1" | "bar.bar2" | "baz.baz1.baz2"` and the `settings` depends on specific `fn` referenced in the definition. You can see the fn names are the concantenated dot paths of the nesting of the callbacks. My current attempts have been to build a discriminated union. For example, if I could generate the following union, it should work, I think.

```
type CallbackDef = {
  name: "foo",
  settings: {
    x: num
  }
} | {
  name: "bar.bar1"
} | {
  name: "bar.bar2"
} | {
  name: "baz.baz1.baz2",
  settings: {
    key: string
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to generate that union dynamically based on the code-declared `callbacks` object. I'm hitting two problems. First, it's clear I need a recursive type here to make this possible, since the nested levels can go many deep. Second, a normal `{ [key in keyof T]: something }` hasn't worked out great because when processing each given object you either return 1 function possibility or, if it's an object, return MULTIPLE function. So it's almost like I want to a spread type of type definition, or have each level return a union of the possibilities at that level. The closest I have is the following:

```
type CallbackFn = (args: any) => any
type CallbackObj = {
    [key: string]: CallbackFn | CallbackObj
}
const callbacks = {
    foo: function(args: { x: number }): string {
        return "test";
    },
    bar: {
        bar1: function(): boolean {
            return true;
        },
        bar2: function(): number {
            return 10;
        }
    },
    baz: {
        baz1: {
            baz2: function(args: { key: string }): string {
            return "test";
            }
        }
    }
}

type StringKeys<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;

type Process<T> = {
    [key in StringKeys<T>]: T[key] extends CallbackFn
    ? { [k in key]: T[key] }
    : {
        [k in StringKeys<T[key]> as `${key}.${k}`]: T[key][k]
    }
}

type GetValues<T> = T[keyof T];

type A = Process<typeof callbacks>
type B = GetValues<A>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=26&pln=1&pc=1#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2BhAhgG2QI0QYwNYDEB2wAvMABSIBOA5gM4Bcwi%20EAlMQHyPMBQo40cJKgw4A8mgBWxYAG9efUAG1sMCAxpgKAS3xUAugyHoseQgB8EKY2MnyQAXzvBMAe3wbnVkdhrS5C0AAzFxcGQIBXfEwwLTdyanpZYAAPBnxwgFs0GApgexZ1TR0qWScAkAoYMHCKQgAiMBgNOoBuMtB7ABp2kAwKBn9yvj6ARjDI6Nj8UgLgNBDkGCZSoaHK6trwCnCYNtWO7v3eygAmcaiYuNn0rJyVo751msIRgAY9o8chrp65xAAvAa-YYAsb3B7Hf5nYARC5TeK0AbAFRqYAabS6PKzdHFcEQp6bBpNMCtYHlL6fX4UhzcJyQWDAADKRV0AGlVDQADwAFU4JAAoslNFgwJyUS5AsBuZ00SyqOw2nSBMAAAoUFyYJpc3l%20X7KVTAHRMuXsiDa9gGKX6iB6YAwIUwfAAE18Rm8BF%20AH4kspDYQUZbudbbdSFECHr6jcyMVRTdrg5xEL4AAYAEhkKPsADp09h7MnA8HlHoqU5HEqGQBxKoANRQO3N0iD4sl3L0ir49LgAEFpGqNVrOV2JZ5hCYaOwK3AAELSatgOvIBuc7vsIA)

There might be an easier way to approach this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type DerivePathAndSettingsUnion<
  T, 
  Path extends string = "", 
  K extends keyof T = keyof T
> = 
  K extends K
    ? T[K] extends (arg: any) => any
      ? Parameters<T[K]>[0] extends undefined
        ? {
            name: `${Path}${K & string}`
          }
        : {
            name: `${Path}${K & string}`,
            settings: Parameters<T[K]>[0]
          }
      : T[K] extends object 
        ? DerivePathAndSettingsUnion<T[K], `${Path}${K & string}.`>
        : never
    : never
```

The type `DerivePathAndSettingsUnion` recursively traverses the object type and takes three generic parameters.

- `T` is the current object type
- `Path` is the current path represented by a dotted string. We use a default value of `""` for the initial call.
- `K` represents the keys of `T` and is always defaulted to `keyof T`. It will never be explicitly provided and is just a shortcut for getting the keys into a generic type.

We [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over the keys of `T` with `K extends K` and check if `K` is a function type.

- If  it is, we can check if the `Parameters<T[K]>[0]` are `undefined` and create the object with `name` and `settings` property based on the result.
- If not, `T[K]` must be an object and we can recursively call `DerivePathAndSettingsUnion` with `T[K]` and the concatenated `Path`, `K` and a `.` at the end. I also added an additional check `T extends object` here which prevents infinite loops if there are any primitives in the object type.

---

We end up with the following result:

```
type Result = DerivePathAndSettingsUnion<typeof callbacks>

// type Result = {
//     name: "foo";
//     settings: {
//         x: number;
//     };
// } | {
//     name: "bar.bar1";
// } | {
//     name: "bar.bar2";
// } | {
//     name: "baz.baz1.baz2";
//     settings: {
//         key: string;
//     };
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAYQIYBsUCMkGMDWAxAOzgF44AKJAJwHMBnALjiQIgEoSA+Jl0SWRVBmw4A8ugBWJOAG9QceXADaOGBEa0wlAJYFqAXUbI0mXITgAfAceFjxoAL6gsAewIa4WQSZy0pskApwAGbOzoxBAK4EWGBarhQ0DDJwAB6MBBEAtugwlHD2rOqaOtQycoEKlDBgEZREAERgMBr1ANzl8vYANB1wmJSM-hUK-QCM4VExcQRkhX2hKDDMZQHDFVU1dXCaETDtq8PdvYH9AEwT0bHxcxnZuStr69W1RKMADPuPjgf5PT+YAC9BscRkgAeMHo9QQDzsFJlcZlQ6IM4Co1HANNpdPk5piSpCoXANi84I1mmA2iDDlT8r1vt9eNB4AARXJaABuMAACkgwAALACCBAAJgBlaqxXS0ACqBGmAB5ygAVLpwco8-lwGApJoi3x47Gker1VXlADSWp1MD1qNUziCcCVUjR9sdoC4pHNlt1wt8Zt6AH5HYozXpvdbfeQkYxmGxONwICCgzzKEhMtVcrR5UqQ3oOIo3mHtT7fFFhTAgjoYMKaUGhoS4AQ0zBGAADAAk0g1fPsnYtADIMcVdPZWzTOjTgT9Hk3023O93e9IB0OsdRR38GxiJSUkinm01KFmc6H84Xx7Tp3BGCei1abc4JDAYmqr-Ig6ztJzu0KxTupbKCq3qqHZdryPZ9nAg4GuuAB0rYcJOjYwJylC9OkKG5KA2HgEycAAErNBEKBgFIn4cty4G-uKYCSnQgGuPKfAwK6njWLgtCISAoAAPQ8dseGEbQxGkaQ-h8RUs4tqSITOJSIASYEtD-siKyKWsaSNlkOSUPs6mdHp-H2BYan8YEUmMPU-SwWM8kScZljiWZCgWaS1lnHZRkmU5knNpZgI2WCoyBTCnkVMptG7lO+kVGiRRroZFT2Il9hAA)

Comment: This is legendary. I'm trying to make sure I understand your technique here. There are two techniques you are employing I wasn't aware of. First, reading on the `K extends K` it looks a creative way to get a foreach union key and ensure that the return is also a union, and since unions of unions combine, it allows us to handle the fact that a nested object returns multiple options. Where as a `{ [key in keyof T]: type }` approach doesn't have that same behavior, only returning one option per key. Also the `{ K & string }`, that looks like an easy way to cast to string?

Comment: `keyof` might return `string`, `number` or `symbol` types. But since a `symbol` is not allowed in template literal types, TypeScript would give an error. By intersecting `K` with `string`, we can ensure that non-`string` types would resolve to `never`, effectively silencing the error.